# Deciding on ThreadPool and Configuration for better performance

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

Below is the use case.

```
Main api
    -> two async external rest call
    combine results of two external rest call
    -> One async external webservice call
    internal computation
```

Used `CompleatableFuture` for async soap webservice call. With executors service pool of 10.

For the two async external rest call, using a new `Executor` service pool. We were thinking should we use `parallelStream` or `ForkJoinPool` or `ExecutorService` here?
Also some tips on the number of threads to keep at each thread pool.

Comment: why are you about to use ThreadPool for two threads? Can't you run a thread for each rest call?

Comment: First two calls are rest web service calls and we need the result immediately to compute something. There we are thinking of one thread pool.   Additionally, the third call is an external soap web service call which we wait for a particular time period from main thread. So we have configured a different threadpool for that.